# Estimating mean of Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, mean

Is there a way, how one can estimate the mean of a neural network $f(\vec{x})$ 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{B}_1} f(\vec{x}) d\vec{x}
$$
efficiently?
Of course, one could sample randomly points from the feature space, propagate them through the network, collect the results, and calculate the arithmetic mean.

The problem with this is though, that, when the network gets too many inputs (for example an image) the curse of dimension would make it unrealistic to sample the feature space densly enough.

So can one somehow use, that one knows the funcitonal form 
$$f(\vec{x}) = \text{softmax}(\text{ReLu}(A_1 \text{ReLu}(A_2...\text{ReLu}(A_N \vec{x})))...) 
$$

Comment: It's not exactly clear what "random" means here. For example if you have a training set of images, how are you defining a random image? Are you picking an image uniformly at random from the set of training images?

Comment: I dont want to look at a training set at all. I want to treat the neural net just like any other probability distribution f(x1,...,xn), that maps the values x1,...xn in R to y in R and than calculate the mean of this function. So by random, I mean any x1,...xn  that lay in the codomain (so in [-1,1])

Comment: If that's the case, why not just randomly sample points to calculate the expectation? There's no magical formula for it, and you'll have to evaluate your network on plenty of samples. However, you allude to having images as inputs, so to me it makes zero sense to place a uniform distribution on your domain, because the expectation would have nothing to do with any of your real samples.

Comment: Because when I want to sample each dimension with only 10 points, and I have, lets say, 512 input dimension, I would have to sample 10^512 points, which is not possible (the curse of dimension)
The arithmetic mean is usually used, if you dont know anything about the underlying process though. Since we actually know the analittical formula, I ask, if one can use that, to approximate the mean analitically/ more efficient, than with the standard arithmetic mean approach.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need uniform measure on your image space? It just seems incredibly adhoc. Otherwise if you insist on uniform measure, you'd probably have to think of neural networks as spin glass models, and use techniques from there, for example this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0233.pdf